# Performing operation along vector in R - only returns a single value

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

I'm trying to perform a conditional operation on a vector `xt`, given a value `lambdat`.
Outside of the `ifelse()` function the operations work, but the full code doesn't. See example below, cheers!

```
xt <- c(1,2,3)
lambdat <- 1
bc_applied_columnt <- ifelse(lambdat != 0, (xt^(lambdat)-1)/lambdat, log(xt))
```

This returns `0` (first value in the vector `xt`), but I'd like it to return the output of `(xt^(lambdat)-1)/lambdat` or `log(xt)` - depending on the condition.

Comment: oops, sorry I just upvoted it - answer accepted now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifelse` returns the output of the same length as the condition that you check. Since `length(lambdat != 0)` is of length 1 `ifelse` returns output of length 1 as well. When you have only one value to check use `if`/`else`.

```
xt <- c(1,2,3)
lambdat <- 1
if(lambdat != 0) (xt^(lambdat)-1)/lambdat else log(xt)
#[1] 0 1 2
```